# How to display data from controller to blade in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have this query in controller that output data as i want. I would like to display total to the view. 
Right now it shows total of the first order to all orders. for example if the first order total is $56, all orders will be $56. How can i show total of every order?

This is how the controller looks like

```
public function viewOrders(User $user)
{
//$seller = Auth::user();
$totals = OrderProduct::select("seller_id", DB::Raw("SUM(Subtotal) AS total"), 'order_id')
->where('seller_id', '=',  \Auth::user()->id)
->groupBy('seller_id')
->groupBy('order_id')
->get();

//dd($totals);


$orders = Order::whereHas('orderItems.product', function ($query) {
    $query->where('seller_id', '=',  \Auth::user()->id);
})->get();

//dd($orders);
return view('orders', ['orders'=> $orders, 'total'=> $totals] );
}
```

when i dd($totals) i get

```
Collection {#278 ▼
#items: array:4 [▼
0 => OrderProduct {#302 ▶}
1 => OrderProduct {#303 ▶}
2 => OrderProduct {#304 ▼
  #table: "order_product"
  #fillable: array:6 [▶]
  #connection: "mysql"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:3 [▶]
  #original: array:3 [▼
    "seller_id" => 1
    "total" => "56"------------------->I would like to show this
    "order_id" => 35
  ]
  #changes: []
}
3 => OrderProduct {#305 ▼
  #table: "order_product"
  #fillable: array:6 [▶
  #attributes: array:3 [▶]
  #original: array:3 [▼
    "seller_id" => 1
    "total" => "112"------------------->I would like to show this
    "order_id" => 36
  ]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
}
]
}
```

Blade view

```
@foreach ($order->orderItems as $item)
@if($item->product->user_id == Auth::user()->id)

   <td>{{ $item->product->name }}</td>
   <td>{{ $item->product->price }}</td>

 @endif
 @endforeach

@foreach($total as $item)
 <td>Total: {{$item->total }}</td>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second foreach loop is likely the issue.  You are in an HTML table.  For each *row*, you are looping through the `orderItems` to make `<td>`s for the product, price, etc.  It looks like you have a single *column* set up for the **Total** field for that item.

So, you are likely only able to write one item's total, since there is no more room on the table to add more `<td>`s.  To see if this is the issue, you can perhaps attempt to put the **totals** into one `<td>` with a pipe in between as a test.  This would go *inside* the first loop:

```
<td>
  @foreach($total as $item)
     {{$item->total }}
     {{ $loop->last?"":" | " }}
  @endforeach
</td>
```

If this is the case, you may want to re-architect for the 3 dimensional **total** per item - perhaps like the test above, or perhaps a single sum of the **totals** per product, etc.  Something to allow for one row to contain one `<td>` for total(s).

Comment: I tried what you suggested and I have got `56 | 56 | 56 | 112`  as output in each order @Watercayman

Comment: Perfect, then you know this is the right solution.  From here, you can decide if you want to sum the totals, average them, etc.  But this has shown that the problem is as described.  Or... you may want to re-think the way you bring in totals - it might be that you wish to move them into the OrderProduct model as a relation / calcualtion / etc. to make sure they align directly with the right product

Comment: My question was I wanted to display each order with it's total let's say first order with total of 56, second order with total of 56 and so on, I didn't want to display all totals at once per each order @Watercayman

Comment: You needed to solve the first issue of the overwriting `<td>` first.  Now that this is resolved, it is simple - you have choices as I said.  To get the order total for the product, just select by the order_id.  Scrap the @foreach loop completely and select the total for that order.  Something like: `$total->where('order_id', $item->id)->first()->total`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get this where do I put `$total->where('order_id', $item->id)->first()->total` @Watercayman

Comment: Inside the original foreach loop, skip the second loop altogether - that was the problem where it was giving you multiple totals.  So, we just want to take the *single* total, as you asked that matches the correct order.  So in the top loop, right below the price, add `<td>`s around that code and it should get you what you want.  I assume the item->id is the order id, though.

Comment: It shows an error `Trying to get property of non-object` when I put  `$total->where('order_id', $item->id)->first()->total`  @Watercayman

Comment: I was assuming the item->id was the order id.  Looks like you've got a second object in the middle. An `order->orderItem`.  You have the *total* tied to the **order_id**, which is going to be the same for every order in the loop.  You are stuck here unless you can tie the total to the *orderItem* and not the *order*.  In other words, you can show the total per each *order* not orderItem.  Your question asked per order - but you are looping on a different object, orderitem, which is not going to work based on the relation (order_id) in the total.

Comment: How can I make it show per order can you help please .If you want more code I can give @ Watercayman

Comment: You *might* be able to do this if you have an `order_id` on the `orderItem` object.  If so, that would tie all three objects together.  If so, you can try the same code as above like this:  `<td>{{$total->where('order_id', $item->order_id)->first()->total}}</td>`  Without getting too deep into your code, this would be best shot if that link is there.  Give it a try.

Comment: Long way around, but got it! :)